# how to find using directives and assembly references

Tags: directive, android-context

VS2022 maui tutorial application.

How do I find a missing directive or assembly reference for an item such as "InsertButton" where the error list of the compiled app notes that 'the name "InsertButton" does not exist in the current context?'
I am looking for an explanation of how to find the specific item that does not exist.
Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;
```

And then use AndroidApp to access what you want in android.